# Is there a way to apply a condition to every argument in *args in Python?

Tags: python, arguments

I am creating a program with finds the HCF of more than 2 numbers. I first created the code which finds the HCF of 2 numbers:

```
def find_hcf(num1, num2):
    for count in range(1, min(num1, num2) + 1):
        if ((num1 % count == 0) and (num2 % count == 0)):
            hcf = count

    return hcf
```

Now I am trying to put *args instead of a fixed amount of arguments.

I am not sure how to apply the `if ((num1 % count == 0) and (num2 % count == 0)):` to `*args`

Comment: `if all(num % count == 0 for num in args):`?

Comment: You could also iterate down instead of up, then you can break out of the loop as soon as you find the common factor.

Comment: Python already provides a built-in function `math.gcd` which can handle multiple numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```py
def find_hcf(*args):
    for count in range(1, min(args) + 1):
        if all(num % count == 0 for num in args):
            hcf = count

    return hcf
```

Comment: Don't use the list comprehension; that requires you to check every `num` even if `args[0] % count != 0`, since the full list of Boolean values is generated before `all` starts iterating. Just use a generator expression `all(num % count == 0 for num in args)` instead.